# Android Default layout

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

so I have this folders with corresponding xml

- layout-sw200dp
- layout-sw600dp
- layout-sw600dp-land
- layout-sw800dp
- layout

my problem is the layout folder automatically detects android wear on device selection preview. I don't want to use my app for android wear How can i remove it? If I change it to another let say Nexus 5 preview I'll be redirect to sw600dp. I want my layout folder to use like a normal handset let say nexus one

Comment: The reason it detects the same is because its the latest version avaialable. Just delete those layout-* folders as @Anton Savin sauggested and you would do fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want your layout to be different on different devices, you can just delete all `layout-*` folders, leaving only the `layout` folder.

Comment: Thanks! I deleted my layout-sw200dp but some devices gave me design errors. what's the best way to fix designs on other devices. Cause I need all of them to be compatible atleast. other devices are not detected by my layout folders

Comment: @user3334111 it's a different question :) depends on the devices you have and on your layout.

Answer (score 0):

**Delete**

```
layout-sw200dp
layout-sw600dp
layout-sw600dp-land
layout-sw800dp
```

And keep only **layout** directory

Answer (score 0):

if you want to disable the screen support then u can do it by using

`<supports-screens android:anyDensity="false"
                      android:largeScreens="false"/>`

and more...by just mentioning it in your `AndroidManifest` file